# Fail to run selenium script with IE 10/11 in Jenkins but fine to FF

Tags: selenium, jenkins

I'm trying to run the selenium scripts with IE 10/11 in Jenkins(Jenkins is running as a windows services), and occured below errors. Any advices for this? by the way, when it start jenkins from command line, this error will not happen.

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with id == outerForm:headerDate (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 60.19 seconds
>   For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
>   Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b1534ae328c771e0856c93e187490ca824', time: '2016-03-15 10:43:46'
>   System info: host: 'CIS-GSSBLD1', ip: '10.1.104.48', os.name: 'Windows Server 2012 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_77'
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
>   Capabilities [{browserAttachTimeout=0, enablePersistentHover=false, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, pageLoadStrategy=normal, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, ignoreZoomSetting=true, handlesAlerts=true, version=11, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, requireWindowFocus=false, browserName=internet explorer, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:26557/, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=true, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=accept}]
>   Session ID: caed7eef-42b7-4585-9fae-eb80f7ee29e8
>   *** Element info: {Using=id, value=outerForm:headerDate}
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:413)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:218)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:355)

Comment: Share your problematic code as well..:)

Comment: Below codes are my method to start IE.

Comment: DesiredCapabilities ieCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
    ieCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);
    ieCapabilities.setCapability("nativeEvents", true);
    ieCapabilities.setCapability("unexpectedAlertBehaviour", "accept");
    ieCapabilities.setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
    ieCapabilities.setCapability("ignoreZoomSetting", true);

Comment: ieCapabilities.setCapability("disable-popup-blocking", true);
    ieCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
    ieCapabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    ieCapabilities.setCapability("requireWindowFocus", false);
    ieCapabilities.setCapability("enablePersistentHover", false);

    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", Constants.excelpath + Constants.ie_explorer);
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieCapabilities);